# Install of Selenium AndroidDriver with Android Debug Bridge (adb) fails with `error: protocol fault (no status)`

Tags: android, macos, selenium, android-emulator

On Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) I'm attempting to install the Selenium AndroidDriver (android-server-2.0.2rc3.apk) with Android SKD R12.

I downloaded the AndroidDriver .apk file in the `tools` directory. Then:

```
$ cd android-sdk/tools
$ ../platform-tools/adb -e install -r android-server-2.0.2rc3.apk
```

Which returned this error:

```
> error: protocol fault (no status)
```

How can I resolve this error, so that I can use adb to install the driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this. Android Debug Bridge (adb) was already running; the process needed to be ended before adb would accept the command. Here's how.

I got the process ID (PID) of adb with:

```
$ ps aux | grep adb
```

Then I killed adb with:

```
$ kill [process id]
```

I was then able to run the install command (`../platform-tools/adb -e install -r android-server-2.0.2rc3.apk`
) successfully.